# PRESTO cannot unnest type: varchar

Tags: split, presto, strsplit, unnest

I have data in a string field without any delimiters and I need to split it out so I can discover the data more clearly. The data in the string looks like this:
{7 items
actionType:"Create"
propertyStatus:"active"
feature:"EID"
hotelID:"23131303"
userCode:"Alexandre Giard"
providerStatus:"active"
statusCode:"Created"
}
and I need to be able to get individual columns for actionType, propertyStatus, feature, hotelID, userCode, providerStatus, statusCode
if have tried cross join unnest and cross join unnest with cast(json()) and several other things and nothing works.

I tried split, but because the only delimiter is the colon, it just splits the single field into a single fields with the colon removed and the data all run together.
I will continue to search the web for information, but if anyone else has run into this situation and has a solution, I would really appreciate some assistance.
I also tried this:

```sql
select  expe_property_id
    , eventdate
     , eventname
       , split_part(t.value, ':', 1)
       , split_part(t.value, ':', 2)
from bexg_prod_project_arm_report.apm_bulk
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(eventdata) AS t(value)
```

and got the error message "CANNOT UNNEST TYPE: VARCHAR"

Comment: Can you please add actual data?

Comment: The data in the string looks like this: {7 items actionType:"Create" propertyStatus:"active" feature:"EID" hotelID:"23131303" userCode:"Alexandre Giard" providerStatus:"active" statusCode:"Created" }

Comment: What have produced such data? Is this what is returned by `select eventdata from table`?

Comment: yes, this is api source data put into presto tables. (i think)

Comment: actually, I think I have received an answer on this specific issue from another source. The solution that works ONLY for this specific type of data (non-delimited list). It does not work in the same way for other json type array lists. solution is    Select id
    , eventdate
    , eventdata
    , cast(json_extract(eventdata, '$.ID') as int) as ID
    , cast(json_extract(eventdata, '$.Status') as varchar) as Status
    , eventname
    from  table
limit 10

Comment: This solution requires `eventdata` to be json. The value you have provided is not a valid json (though it looks very close) - that is why I was asking about the actual data.